# Is "princessship" a real word? Are there any other words which have the same letter 3 times consecutively?

Tags: orthography, is-it-a-word, repetition

One of my friends argues that *princessship* is the only word which has 3 identical letter comes together (**s**) ,but I think there is no word such as *princessship*.

Can anyone tell me whether this is a real word, and if there are any more English words which have 3 letters consecutively?

Comment: Just FYI, in German there are actually quite a few of words with three consecutive identical letters. Not loads, but enough.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: In Russian, there are two words which have three consecutive letters e (all pronounced [ye])

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no word with three consecutive letters under the most narrow definition of "real word", but there are several words of the following types:

1. There are many acronyms/initialisms that contain triple letters, like *AAA*, *AIEEE*, *KKK*, *WWW*, or Roman numerals like *xviii*.
2. There are place names, like

   - *Kaaawa*, a [place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ka%CA%BBa%CA%BBawa,_Hawaii) in Hawaii.
   - *Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch*, a [place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll) in Wales.
3. There are names of people with all sorts of unconventional spellings, like *Minnnie*, *Annnora*, or *Diannne*.
4. There are interjections like *mmm*, *hmmm*, *zzz*, etc.
5. There are archaic/poetic words with elided letters, like *whenceeer* (really, *whencee'er* from *whenceever*), *wheree'er*, etc.
6. Finally, there are words which would probably be written with a hyphen whenever used, like *frillless* (mentioned by Dusty) which is really *frill-less*, similarly *bulllike*, *gulllike*, *wallless*, many words ending in *-ss-ship* like your *princessship*, *bossship*, *goddessship*, *headmistressship*, *patronessship*.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not a native speaker, but I'm under the impression that words with the same letter repeated three times are either elided so that they contain two, or are spelled with a hyphen.

For instance *cross-section* (hyphenated) or *chaffinch* (where the 3rd 'f' is omitted)

Comment: +1 for thinking of chaffinch. No-one else has mentioned ellipses like this.

Comment: +1 I typically see such words drop a letter (as crossection, although that word I've never seen conjoined, only as two words)

Comment: Along the same lines, *free* + *-est* → *freest*.

Comment: *See + -er = seer*

Comment: As ShreevatsaR mentions, you get cases where a word ending with a double letter has a suffix beginning with the same terminating letter. They're *often* spelled with a hyphen (or just avoided). But not absolutely always. So e.g. some people would write "gillless", even though "gill-less" arguably looks clearer. The thing is that these are really corner cases.

Answer (score 10):

I believe *princessship* is typically spelled with a hyphen *princess-ship*, although I do remember references to it without.  However, if your friend is willing to allow *princessship* as a word, certainly words like *dutchessship*, *governessship*, *countessship*, etc. would also qualify.

So one way or another, you can prove your friend wrong =D

Edit: A quick search also brings up *frillless* which has an entry in OED

Comment: Thanks. is there any valid english word which have 3 letters continously?

Answer (score 3):

Discounting acronyms, for words without hyphens that have three consecutive letters, the OED lists these:

> brrr, countessship, duchessship, frillless, governessship, grrr, grrrl, hostessship, postmistressship

For words that have a letter, a hyphen, then that same letter twice repeated, it lists these:

> eve-eel, paste-eel, salpingo-oöphorectomy, salpingo-oöphoritis, slime-eel, snipe-eel, spine-eel

For words where you have the same letter twice, then the hyphen, then that same letter again, it has all these:

> ass-ship, ball-less, ball-lightning, ball-like, bee-eater, bell-less, boss-ship, boss-shot, boss-stone, brass-smith, burgess-ship,
>   call-letter, call-loan, carcass-shell, cell-layer, cell-less, cell-like, cell-lineage, cell-lined, chaff-flower, class-subject, compass-saw,
>   compass-signal, compass-stock, cross-saddle, cross-sea, cross-section, cross-sectional, cross-sectioning, cross-seizing, cross-sell,
>   cross-shed, cross-shoot, cross-shot, cross-sleeper, cross-spall, cross-spider, cross-springer, cross-staff, cross-stitch, cross-stone,
>   cross-street, cuckoo-orchis, cypress-spurge, demigoddess-ship, distress-sale, doll-land, dress-shield, egg-glass, fall-leaf, fall-less,
>   fee-estate, fee-expectant, frill-lizard, fusee-engine, gall-leaf, gall-less, gill-lamella, gill-less, gill-lid, glass-sand, glass-shaped,
>   glass-shell, glass-shrimp, glass-slag, glass-snail, glass-snake, glass-soap, glass-sponge, goddess-ship, grass-seeder, grass-siding,
>   grass-snake, grass-snipe, grass-sparrow, grass-spirit, grass-sponge, grass-spring, head-mistress-ship, ill-less, ill-lived, ill-looking,
>   ill-lookingness, isinglass-stone, Jaycee-ette, joss-stick, kill-lamb, kiss-sky, knee-elbow position, mastiff-fox, mill-lands, mill-leat,
>   mill-lodge, miss-stays, mistress-ship, moss-seat, moss-starch, no-see-em, off-faller, off-falling, off-farm, off-field, pass-shooting,
>   patroness-ship, poss-stick, press-shy, press-stone, press-stud, princess-ship, process-server, puff-fish, quill-less, seamstress-ship,
>   see-er, see-everything, shell-less, shell-lettuce, shell-lime, skull-less, small-leaved, smell-less, stall-literature, still-liquor,
>   stress-strain, three-edged, three-eight, till-land, toll-lodge, troll-line, wall-less, wall-lining, wall-lizard, well-laboured,
>   well-labouring, well-laced, well-laden, well-laid, well-languaged, well-learned, well-leaved, well-led, well-legged, well-lettered,
>   well-lighted, well-liked, well-liking, well-limbed, well-limned, well-lined, well-lit, well-liveried, well-living, well-loaded, well-lodged,
>   well-looked, well-looking, well-loved, well-lunged, will-less, will-lessly, witness-stand, zoo-organic

Alas, there appear to be **no instances of *four* letters in a row**, even if separated by a hyphen or an apostrophe, such as **Kwanzaa-aardvark*, **frisbee-eel*, **tatoo-ooze*, **install-llama*, or **chimpanzee-eerie*.

I see a product opportunity here. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about "Wiiitis"? Although I'm not sure the word is considered a "real word".

> Wiiitis -- pronounced “wee-eye-tis” -- is the latest ailment to develop from the video game era
> https://www.reuters.com/article/us-wii-elbow/if-its-not-tennis-elbow-it-may-be-wiiitis-idUSN0616721120070606