# Word with three consecutive L's

Tags: single-word-requests

In a fun discussion, someone used the sentence

> That guy is ballless.

I can see a slang definition on urbandictionary but this led to a question. Are there words with 3 consecutive l's in them (preferably not scientific words, technical words or abbreviations)?

Comment: Dear close voter - I dont see how this is "not constructive" - It's asking for a single word if one exists. If not, the question can be ignored.

Comment: I voted to close. This question is "not constructive" because it's not helping you solve a problem, and I don't think it's particularly useful. I am just one person; other people may not agree with me.

Comment: I know a sentence with ten of the same word consecutively but I don't know any words with the same letter appearing more than twice in a row. Except for the likes of "aaaaaaarrrgh!"

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15786

Comment: @nico: That dupe is a good find, thanks. Better reason to close IMO ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is "princessship" a word? Are there other words in which the same letter appears three times consecutively?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15786/is-princessship-a-word-are-there-other-words-in-which-the-same-letter-appears)

Comment: Although this question is marked "not constructive," I voted to close because it is a duplicate of another question.  I feel this is a more accurate close reason than "not constructive," particularly since it duplicates a question that was not closed.

Comment: #egrep -e '(.)\1\1' /usr/share/dict/words
bossship
demigoddessship
goddessship
headmistressship
patronessship
wallless
whenceeer

Comment: [*Shellless*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shellless) is a possible example. It is sometimes spelled *shell-less* to avoid the awkward triple *l*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [this](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2alll%2a&scwo=1&sswo=1) search is quite a good proof that there are no such words that are common.

Do note however that the above search is limiting it to common words, which for onelook means to be found in six dictionaries or more.

Here is list of [all](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2alll%2a&scwo=1&scwo=0&sswo=0) results, some of which refer to references that you might consider acceptable, e.g. [illlooking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/illlooking?r=66)

> **adjective**
>   *Older Use*
>   1. ugly.
>   2. sinister.
>   Origin: 1625–35

Answer (score 1):

Edit: All those words listed previously could have been written in a different way, or are actually currently being written in a different way (e.g. "Bull like" or "Bull-like")

I could only find one word that was spelt with three "l's" as it's only spelling:

> [Quintilllion:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quintilllion) According to the French notation, which is used on the Continent and in America, the cube of a million, or a unit with eighteen ciphers annexed; according to the English notation, a number produced by involving a million to the fifth power, or a unit with thirty ciphers annexed.

Comment: seems even quini*ll*ion is valid?

Comment: Neither Wikipedia nor Wiktionary is aware of quintilllion.  I think it's spurious.

Comment: Not even the OALD or the NOAD list it.

Comment: Apparently Webster's Dictionary lists it.

Comment: If you mean the Merrian-Webster, then [it doesn't](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quintilllion).

Comment: Nup, Webster's Revised Unabridged, 1913 edition