# How many "L"s in shell + -ly

Tags: suffixes

I'd like to apply the *-ly* suffix to *shell* but I'm not sure how many *L* it should have? Three like *shellly* or two like *shelly*?

Is there a rule that can be used with other suffixes too if the suffix makes the last letter to occur threefold?

---

Background: It should be a project name derived from *shell* as a user interface.

Comment: Use a different variant -- _shellish_ or _shell-like_, for instance.

Comment: @JohnLawler I find it's not that _catchy_ ;-)

Comment: ***Shelly*** : http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shelly

Comment: The rule is, no three successive *L*'s unbroken in a word. It's not just a good idea, it's the law.

Comment: @Robusto: That must be why there isn't any three-l lllama (see Ogden Nash).

Comment: If it's not this, people then it's been done: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelly

Comment: @t3chb0t How about leaving out the hyphen? *Shelllike!*

Comment: Since Shelly is a proper name as well, it is perfectly reasonable as a project name. Also, names do not need to follow rules of grammar.

Comment: Here's a more thorough explanation of the English words with a letter repeated three times in a row:  http://english.stackexchange.com/a/15788/10044 (in short: no "real" words)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a productive suffix, *-ly* is added only to adjectives. (There are a few existing adjectives in *-ly*, such as *untimely*, but it is not productive). So unless you have coined a new adjective *shell* ("That's very shell!") such a coinage is unlikely to be understood.

Having said that, adjectives in *-ll* do form adverbs in *-lly*: eg *dull*, *dully*. But I think most people seeing *shelly* would assume it was *shell + -y*, i.e. "shell-like", or "full of shells", "made of shell".

Comment: And I wonder if OP actually seeks an adjective, so shell-y will do just fine. I also like shellic, but only because it sounds like shellac.

Comment: Or characterized by shells. *Small **shelly** fauna* is a term of art in paleontology.

Comment: @StoneyB: no, I don't. I mean "added only to adjectives to form adverbs".

Comment: @Unrelated the meaning I seek is _shell-like_ so if most people would think of it like this then it works for me. Of course in this specific context - this is, user interface.

Comment: @ColinFine Ah, of course you do.

Comment: The suffix being added to "shell" is "-y", not "-ly". That is a common way to form adjectives from nouns, e.g. hairy, milky, spicy, etc.

Comment: Also, "lll" simply never happens in English.