# Why is it forbidden for English words to contain the same letter 3 times in a row?

Tags: orthography

I am wondering why it is forbidden for English to have the same three letters in a row, as in *Goddessship*?

Why is it that words like *Goddessship*, *frillless*, *beeeater*, and *skulllike* either are hyphenated (*Goddess-ship*, *frill-less*, *bee-eater*, *skull-like*) or have one of the letters dropped (*Goddesship*, *frilless*, *beeater*, *skullike*).

Why can't they have the same three letters in a row?

Comment: It isn't necessarily totally forbidden. See the following dictionary entries for [headmistressship](https://www.onelook.com/?w=headmistressship); also the examples in the following related post [Is “princessship” a real word? Are there any other words which have the same letter 3 times consecutively?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15786)

Comment: Because if three were routinely used, someone would ask 'Why is it forbidden in English to have the same 4 letters in a row?' Seriously, it gets hard to read consecutive l's say. The Germans have a special way of writing _sss_ to aid readability.

Comment: No one wrote down a rule when designing English to explicitly forbid triple letters. It's just not common and it's difficult to pronounce and in very different situation difficult to read.

Comment: This is not a fact which is unique to English. The same certainly applies in French, with the exception that where it is necessary to add a feminine e at the end of a past participle, to achieve agreement with a feminine noun, you can get a word that ends *...eée* - as in *une maison créée* - a created house.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "princessship" a real word? Are there any other words which have the same letter 3 times consecutively?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15786/is-princessship-a-real-word-are-there-any-other-words-which-have-the-same-let)

Comment: Forbidden? In English? Nahhhh. Who is there to forbid it?

Comment: This is soooooooooooo not a duplicate.

Comment: @WS2 Romanian, on the other hand, does have several well-known examples. "Copil" means "child". "Copii" means "children". "Copiii" means "the children". It also has a few thrice-repeated pairs of letters: "lalea" means "tulip". "Lalele" = "tulips". "Lalelele" = "the tulips".

Comment: @Chuckk Similarly, the first person singular potential of the Finnish verb _enetä_ ‘increase, enlarge’ is _enenenen_, its negated form being _en enenene_; Estonian has (somewhat recherché) compounds like _jäääärne_ ‘on the edge of the ice’ and _töööö_ ‘a work night’; and the (even more recherché) Japanese sentence 「東欧を覆おう」 ‘let us cover Eastern Europe’ is _tōō o ōōu_, or in JSL romanisation, _toooo o oooou_.

Comment: Oh come on. Can't you really see why it's poor style? If not try ELL.

Comment: Because early printers only had so many copies of each letter.

Comment: @David Poor style and orthographic impossibility are two very different things. And to suggest that someone who is to all appearances a native English speaker should be shifted off to a site specifically targeted towards non-native learners because they disagree with you about style is, frankly, quite insulting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an invalid assertion.

Comment: In order to enhance the pronunciation of a letter -  'l' for example - it can be doubled. But adding a third will not achieve anything further, phonetically, except in a ludicrous or comical context. I don't think it is a 'rule', it is just a practical matter.

Comment: @Mitch This is why we call wee eels *elvers*, doncha know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where, but I read a guideline in one source that said to remove the third consecutive instance of a letter, or to use a hyphen to separate the parts in the case of a compound word, because English doesn't allow three of the same letter in a row. That seems foolish to me, amounting to *inferring* that such a rule must exist to explain why people rarely encounter such a thing, when in reality one rarely sees it only because it hardly ever comes up.

And, yet, we do clearly apply that rule when we put a verb that ends in "-ee" into the past tense, as in "to tree": "The barking dog treed the cat." I wonder how many people would spell it "treeed".

Yet I would write "brasssmith" for someone who works with brass, just as I write "goldsmith" and "silversmith". Others might write "brass-smith".

For what it's worth, French and Dutch have no such concern: French has "créée" ("created", feminine), and Dutch has numbers like "tweeëntachtig" = "eighty-two" ("two-and-eighty").

Comment: I don’t think _treed_ (or to use a perhaps more commonly heard word, _freed_) are much to go by as parallels. The e in _-(e)d_ is also frequently suppressed if there’s just one e in the root: _hated_, _named_, _used_, etc. The past tense marker is really just _-d_, with some fairly intricate rules (and exception) that determine when we add a connection _-e-_ in spelling, and an unrelated set of rules and exceptions that determine when we add a euphonic /ə/ in speech.

Comment: I only know a little French and no Dutch but I notice that the French example you give has two 'Es' with acute accents and one without whilst the Dutch example has one with an umlaut. In terms of ease of reading this means that your examples only have two consecutive identical letters. Because English has no pronunciation marks like accents or umlauts we can't put three together and still make them easy to read.

Comment: @BoldBen That’s not an umlaut in Dutch: it’s a diaeresis. Dutch doesn’t have diacritic umlaut. A diaeresis creates a new syllable where there otherwise would not be one. It’s for splitting up the second of two vowels via an introduced hiatus that would otherwise fuse into the same syllable (so like in French or English or Spanish) rather than for mutating the existing vowel via fronting or rounding (so like in German or Hungarian), Completely different things altogether.

Comment: @tchrist I concede to your greater knowledge. As you can tell from my use of the word  _umlaut_ I was assuming that Dutch used the mark in the same way as German. My fault for making assumptions.